# xgbTree fails with non-formula for caret training

Tags: r, r-caret, xgboost

I'm trying to fit a `xgbTree` model using the `train` function from the `caret` package.

**EDIT:** Here is a sample dataset to make the example reproducable. I've also converted all variables to numeric as suggested:

```
df<-data.frame(
x1=c(-231,5,-166,-158,170,-243,-184,25,-130,-209,453,-46,-13,-247,-74,-209,-130,-118,10,40),
x2=c(2,48,6,7,24,2,5,7,12,48,48,24,2,8,4,1,8,5,50,6),
x3=c(6, 3, 2, 1, 2, 6, 0, 6, 2, 4, 5, 5, 2, 4, 1, 2, 3, NA, 0, 1),
x4=c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
x5=c(45.1, 58.6, 41.3, 58.6, 45.1, 60.8, 44.1, 58.6, 38.8, 40.5, 60.8, 45.1, 41.3, 45.1, 41.3, 45.1, 39, 41.3, 51.7, 51.7),
x6=c(0, 2, 4, 0, NA, 0, 1, 0, NA, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0),
x7=c(NA, 6, 6, NA, 6, NA, 3, NA, 6, NA, 6, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA),
x8=c(0, 1, 4, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
x9=c(0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
x10=c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
y=c(0.00272609554964902, 0.00196386488609584, 0.0169606512890095, 0, 0.00978263953223331, 0.00310850075796128, 0.0225595119926366, 0.00456053067993367, 0.00980320074504326, 0.0116718460483506, 0.0618914994405961, 0.0420972062763108, 0.00139303482587065, 0.0426927149151269, 0.0248756218905473, 0, 0, 0.000855672497463542, 0.0287026406429392, 0.00190374657325617))
```

When I'm using the formula interface everything works fine:

**EDIT:** used libraries added

```
library(caret)
library(doParallel)

registerDoParallel(cores=n) 

xgb_model <-train(y ~.,
                     data = df,
                     method = "xgbTree",
                     na.action = na.pass)
```

But the model training fails when I'm using the non-formula interface:

```
xgb_model <-train(x=df[,-ncol(df)],
                  y=df[,ncol(df)],
                     data = df,
                     method = "xgbTree",
                     na.action = na.pass)
```

I've already tried omitting all NA's, as well as using only specific variables to narrow down the problem, but I couldn't really find any issues in regard to the input data.

The actual `data.frame` looks like this:

```
'data.frame':   433 obs. of  30 variables:
 $ x1      : int  -231 5 -166 -158 170 -243 -184 25 -130 -209 ...
 $ x2      : int  2 48 6 7 24 2 5 7 12 48 ...
 $ x3      : Ord.factor w/ 7 levels "0"<"1"<"2"<"3"<..: 4 3 2 3 7 1 7 3 5 6 ...
 $ x4      : Ord.factor w/ 8 levels "0"<"1"<"2"<"3"<..: 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 ...
 $ x5      : num  45.1 58.6 41.3 58.6 45.1 60.8 44.1 58.6 38.8 40.5 ...
 $ x6      : int  0 2 4 0 NA 0 1 0 NA 0 ...
 $ x7      : Ord.factor w/ 6 levels "1"<"2"<"3"<"4"<..: NA 6 6 NA 6 NA 3 NA 6 NA ...
 $ x8      : Ord.factor w/ 5 levels "0"<"1"<"2"<"3"<..: 1 2 5 1 5 1 3 1 2 1 ...
 $ x9      : Ord.factor w/ 5 levels "0"<"2"<"4"<"6"<..: 1 1 5 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ x10     : int  NA NA NA NA 0 NA 0 NA NA NA ...
 $ x11     : Ord.factor w/ 10 levels "0"<"2"<"4"<"5"<..: 7 5 1 5 4 4 9 7 5 8 ...
 $ x12     : Ord.factor w/ 32 levels "0"<"1"<"2"<"3"<..: 10 2 1 13 1 10 6 6 1 1 ...
 $ x13     : Ord.factor w/ 13 levels "0"<"0.7"<"1.4"<..: 1 1 1 8 1 1 13 6 1 6 ...
 $ x14     : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 2 1 1 4 1 2 4 1 4 4 ...
 $ x15     : int  1 2 3 1 2 1 1 9 2 2 ...
 $ x16     : int  180 200 160 250 120 160 300 600 180 150 ...
 $ x17     : Ord.factor w/ 6 levels "1"<"2"<"3"<"4"<..: 2 6 5 3 2 2 1 3 2 2 ...
 $ x18     : Ord.factor w/ 5 levels "1"<"2"<"3"<"4"<..: 4 1 2 3 5 3 4 4 5 5 ...
 $ x19     : num  366825 509200 353760 502500 306666 ...
 $ x20     : num  2 2 2 2 2.83 ...
 $ x21     : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ x22     : int  50 70 32 48 20 56 57 51 53 55 ...
 $ x23     : int  5 2 5 5 2 3 3 2 4 1 ...
 $ x24     : int  0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ x25     : int  0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ x26     : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ x27     : Ord.factor w/ 5 levels "12"<"13"<"14"<..: NA NA 3 3 1 5 1 5 5 5 ...
 $ x28     : Ord.factor w/ 9 levels "4"<"6"<"7"<"8"<..: 7 7 2 NA 4 6 8 NA 4 9 ...
 $ x29     : num  -0.3211 -0.0462 -0.8133 0.3825 -0.5475 ...
 $ y       : num  0.00273 0.00196 0.01696 0 0.00978 ...
```

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting? Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Sharing data from `str()` isn't helpful, perhaps use `dput()` instead. Do you have the variable `y` defined? Does `dataset[,y]` actually return the column of interest for you?

Comment: I've added a reproducable example. The error I'm getting from caret is not very helpful, therefore I haven't added it here. The error is: 'Error in train.default(x = df[, -ncol(df)], y = df[, ncol(df)],  : 
  Stopping'

Answer (score 1):

Form `?train` help referring to the `train(x, y, ...)` interface:

> The predictors in x can be most any object as long as the underlying model fit function can deal with the object class.

The underlying `xgb.DMatrix` function (you can see all the functions in caret's xgboost wrapper from `getModelInfo('xgbTree')`) expects a numeric matrix as input, so you get an error. The formula `train` interface works because it uses `model.matrix` under the hood to convert your formula into a numeric matrix, including the encoding of factor variables. To use the (x,y) interface, you first have to convert your data.frame into a matrix. Either `model.matrix` or `caret::dummyVars` are popular options to help with that.

Of note: you have many ordinal factor variables in your data. Since trees can easily handle any non-uniformity of ordinal intervals, for tree-based non-parametric algorithms, it is better to simply convert each ordinal factor into single-column numeric instead of creating multiple dummy variables out of them.

Comment: I've tried converting my data.set to numeric values and also converted the data into a matrix using 'as.matrix(sapply(df, as.numeric))', but I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The `data=` and `na.action=` parameter should only be used with the formula version of `train()`. This means you should either use

```
xgb_model <- train(y ~.,
                 data = df,
                 method = "xgbTree",
                 na.action = na.pass)
```

or

```
xgb_model <- train(x=df[,-ncol(df)],
                  y=df[,ncol(df)],
                  method = "xgbTree")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that the problem was not caused by any mistake in the `train()` command, but by the attempt to parallelize the model using `registerDoParallel(cores=n)` from the `doParallel` package. `doParallel` works fine with all other models I've tested so far in `caret` (namely `treebag`, `cforest` and `gbm`).

So the following code works fine, given that you don't use `doParallel`:

```
xgb_model <- train(x=df[,-ncol(df)],
                  y=df[,ncol(df)],
                  method = "xgbTree")
```